# AggregateResult Number format in Visualforce Page

Tags: aggregateresult, decimal

Hi all I have an aggregateResult query which is pulling correctly into a visualforce page block table.
All the numbers are have 0 digits right of decimal but the values display with one 0 to the right. Example: 510.0 instead of 510.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Also, can the numbers be displayed with the thousands (and more) commas?

Thanks

Edited to show code sample

```
public List<AggregateResult> getAggregateList(){
            Parent_Custom_object__c TheCS = (Parent_Custom_object__c)sc.getRecord();
            List<AggregateResult> AggResults = new List <AggregateResult>();

         AggregateResult[] aggQuery = [select
     zone__c zone,
      SUM(Added_Value__c)TotalAddedValue,
      SUM(delivered_units__c)TotalDelivered
      from Custom_Child_object__c 
      where Parent_of_Custom_Child_object__c =:TheCS.id
      GROUP BY zone__c    
             ]; 

     if(aggQuery!=null){
         for(AggregateResult QAR:aggQuery)
      {
        AggResults.add(QAR); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a wrapper if you need to convert the results in Apex:

```
public class Wrapper {
    public Integer totalAddedValue { get; set; }
    public Integer totalDelivered { get; set; }
    public String zone { get; set; }
    public Wrapper(AggregateResult result) {
        totalAddedValue = ((Decimal)result.get('TotalAddedValue')).intValue();
        totalDelivered = ((Decimal)result.get('TotalDelivered')).intValue();
        zone = (String)result.get('zone');
    }
}
```

---

```
for(AggregateResult QAR:aggQuery) {
    AggResults.add(new Wrapper(QAR)); 
}
```

This will add a lot more Apex code, but eliminate the need for ROUND in the Visualforce markup.

---

## Original Answer

---

Numeric values in an AggregateResult (aside from `COUNT()`) are Decimal values. Visualforce will show these with a decimal point by default. Use a function such as `ROUND()` in your code to remove it. Here's an example:

```
public class controller {
    public Decimal value { get; set; }
    public controller() {
        value = 5.0;
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="controller">
    Using ROUND: {!ROUND(value,0)}<br />
    Not Using ROUND: {!value}
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Is there a way to use ROUND in the aggregate query?

Comment: @jaw999 No. The alternative would be to write a wrapper class, transfer the data from the AggregateResult object to this wrapper (converting the values from Decimal to Integer), then display the wrapper values.

Comment: I have added code for clarity. Not sure where to push the ROUND function

Comment: @jaw999 Added the Apex code version that you'd use. Also, P.S. the result of a query is never a null variable, so no need to do `if(aggQuery != null)`.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting an error of Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(CustomAdZoneTotals2.Wrapper) from the type List<AggregateResult>  - an issue with how my wrapper is set?

Comment: @jaw999 you'll need to change the data type of the list to Wrapper. The data type of the list must match what's being put in to it.